# Fail to strip \r in string

Tags: python, string, escaping

I've one system in python, where these system create a socket and receives information from trackers installed in trucks and cars.

One of these trackers, send strings with `\r` as separator. But, when i get this string, i try to split that string for `\r`, but don't work.

So i try to strip these char from my strings, but also don't work. Here's a little piece of my code:

```
try:
    self.msg = self.client_conn.recv(settings.CONNECTION["BYTES_TO_RECEIVED"])

    # Se não ter nenhuma mensagem, sai fora do loop
    if not self.msg:
        break

    # Faz a validação da mensagem
    if self.validate_message():

        # Loop para passar por cada linha
        for self.msg in self.split_messages():
            # Remove outros caracteres
            self.msg = str(self.msg).strip('\r\n').replace("\r", "")
            print "Mensagem: " + repr(self.msg)

            # Insere na fila
            self.insert_queue()

            # Continua o loop
            continue

except:
    # Insere nos logs
    logger.Log(
        logger.Log.LISTENER,
        logger.Log.WARNING,
        "O TRACKER %s:%s FECHOU A CONEXÃO" % self.client_info
    )
    # Sai do loop
    break
```

My function called split_message is this:

```
def split_messages(self):
        # Retorna o split das linhas
        return self.msg.split('\\r')
```

So, my message isn't splitted, when i save this string in my database, i get some char at end:

[image: Database]

How can i handle this? I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is two questions.  To answer the first probably solves the second.

Have you tried using the **.rstrip()** method?

```
your_string.rstrip()
```

If you want to split the lines on \r or new lines use the python splitlines.

```
your_string.splitlines()
```

Comment: Sometimes, the strings comes like this "ASDASD\rDSADAFJASF\rSDAHGYSD". So, that's why i try to split first

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this function:

```
def split_messages(self):
        # Retorna o split das linhas
        return self.msg.split('\\r')
```

Note that you're not splitting on the single character `\r`, you're attempting to split on a pair of characters `\\r` (the first slash escapes the second as a literal slash character).

```
>>> s = "1\r2\r3\r4"
>>> s.split('\r')
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

(split returns a list of the strings separated by the `\r` character)

```
>>> s.split('\\r')
['1\r2\r3\r4']
```

(split returns a list containing the entire string, because the requested `\\r` separator isn't in there...)